# Where to securely store certs/keys when using PHP/MySQLI/Apache?

Tags: php, security, ssl, mysqli, certificate

I have separate web (Apache/PHP) and database (MySQL) servers using mysqli over an SSL connection working nicely.  In the ssl_set() function in the database connection library within the framework, I can specify the path to the keys/pem files as long as it's within the docroot.  If the files are outside the docroot, I obviously cannot access them, and the connection fails.

What is the most secure method for storing and accessing mysql client ssl keys outside the apache docroot?

Is there a secure use of "ini_set" whereby I can allow that access "on the fly" and then remove that parameter?  Or should I use symlinks?

I'm looking for best practices here.  I suppose this question isn't limited to cert keys, but I wanted to make sure you knew my specific use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for best practices here. I suppose this question isn't limited to cert keys, but I wanted to make sure you knew my specific use case.

This problem gets into a the territory where security experts will split hairs over trade-offs against different threat models, so there is no "one right answer" for secure credential management. However, there are a ton of obviously wrong answers.

Chris Cornutt published an article about [securing PHP credentials with Docker](https://websec.io/2018/07/22/Docker-Secure-Credentials.html) that I highly recommend reading for background information about the threats and strategies involved in solving credential management.

In general, [psecio/secure_dotenv](https://github.com/psecio/secure_dotenv) will solve this problem for most users. This is an open source library for managing credentials that stores them encrypted at-rest.

If you need something fancier (or to integrate with a product, e.g. Vault), you may want to ask a security expert to review your designs and implementations.