# MySQL Credential Storage

Tags: php, python, mysql, security, apache2

**Introduction**
When storing MySQL credentials, I understand that the php.ini file can store defaulted values and I imagine something similar for python.  However, since I'm having php, python and possible more scripts interact with the MySQL database, I've decided to do something else.

I have a directory(**A**) which is recursively owned by www-data and under this directory(**A**), is the apache's served directory(**B**).  Also under the principal directory (**A**), I have another hidden directory(**C**) which stores a hidden .ini file(**x**) with permissions 700 that stores **MySQL credentials**.  In this directory (**C**), there hidden scripts - a python(**y0**) and a php(**y1**) script - which parse the .ini file(**x**) to get the credentials.

In the served directory(**B**), for example, there is one php script(**z1**) that includes php .ini parser(**y1**).  This script(**z1**) opens MySQL connections.  Other scripts include this(**z1**) so they can actually query the MySQL DB.

Note that any file specified is at most 770 permissions and all are owned by www-data.

**Question**
After having said all of this, **is there a better/safer way of doing this?** I just felt like storing the credentials in one hidden location outside of the served directory vs many locations (php.ini file, etc) that are actually well-defined, well-visible seemed more appropriate.

Comment: Why are you using hidden directories? That seems obnoxious. Why not just store it in a JSON file outside your web root, something both Python and PHP can parse?

Comment: Maybe hidden directories is over the top; however, I don't see what's better about a JSON over .ini.  Python and PHP can both parse .ini

Comment: The INI file format is really limited by comparison, it's also not a standard so there's a lot of variation in how they work. Hidden directories provide zero security and just make life harder for those who have to fix your site in an emergency situation. Keep your configuration files outside your web root and you won't have problems with them leaking out.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I mean, I'm really not doing anything complicated so how limited .ini is isn't that big of a concern to me.  I guess it not being a standard though is a more appropriate reason to use .ini.  Again, thanks

Comment: One common practice is to store your configuration values in environment variables and using `os.getenv()` or similar to retrieve them. This can be tricky with something like Django, but it separates configuration from application which is good for security and portability.

Comment: if you are using MySQL 5.6.6 or later, you can make use of this feature http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html its not totally secure but a little better to having credentials in hidden files.

Comment: I've answered the general problem of secure credential storage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11744957/2224584), if it helps.