# Safe place to store an encrypt/decrypt key using PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, security, cookies, encryption

I just want everyone to know that I am in no way a professional web developer nor a security expert. Well, I'm not a beginner either. You can say that I am an amateur individual finding interest in web development.

And so, I'm developing a simple, small, and rather, a personal web app (though I'm thinking of sharing it to some friends and any individual who might find it interesting) that audits/logs every expense you take so you can keep track of the money you spend down to the last bit. Although my app is as simple as that (for now).

[image: Screenshot]

Since I'm taking my app to be shared to some friends and individuals as a factor, I already implemented a login to my application. Although it only needs the user key, which acts as the username and password at the same time.

I've used jQuery AJAX/PHP for the login authentication, as simple as getting the text entered by such user in the textbox, passing it to jQuery then passing it to the PHP on the server to verify if such user exists. And if yes, the user will be redirected to the main interface where his/her weekly expense will be logged.

Much for that, my main problem and interest is within the security, I've formulated a simple and a rather weak security logic where a user can't get to the main interface without having to login successfully first. The flow is like this.

> when a user tries to go the main interface (dashboard.php) without successfully logging in on the login page (index.php), he will then be prompted something like "you are not able to view this page as you are not logged in." and then s/he will be redirected back to the login page (index.php)

How I've done this is rather simple:

Once a user key has been verified and the user is logged in successfully, cookies will then be created (and here is where my dilemma begins). the app will create 2 cookies, 1 is 'user_key' where the user key will be stored; and 2 is 'access_auth' where the main interface access is defined, true if logged in successfully and false if wrong or invalid user key.

Of course I'm trying to make things a little secure, I've encrypted both the cookie name and value with an openssl_encrypt function with 'AES-128-CBC' with PHP here, each and every user key has it's own unique iv_key to be used with the encryption/decryption of the cookie and it's values. I've encrypted the cookie so it wouldn't be naked and easily altered, since they won't know which is which. Of course, the encrypted text will vary for every user key since they have unique iv_keys although they have same 'key' values hard-coded in the PHP file.

> pretty crazy right ?. yea i know, just let me be for that. and as how the main interface (dashboard.php) knows if a user has been logged in or not and to redirect them back to the login page (index.php) is purely easy. 'that' iv_key is stored together with the user_key row in the [database](https://i.imgur.com/pXW9gEP.png).

I've attached a JavaScript in the main interface (dashboard.php) which will check if the cookie is equal to 2, if it is less than or greater than that, all those cookies will be deleted and then the user will redirected to the login page (index.php).

```
var x = [];
var y = 0;

//Count Cookie
$.each($.cookie(), function(z){
    x[y] = z;
    y++;
});

//Check if Cookie is complete
if (x.length != 2) {
    //If incomplete Cookie - delete remaining cookie, prompt access denied, and redirect to login page
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        $.removeCookie(x[i], { path: '/' });
    };
    alert("You are not allowed to enter this page as you are not yet logged in !.");
    window.location.href = "index.php";
} else {
    //If complete Cookie - authenticate cookie if existing in database
}
```

As you can see, the code is rather incomplete, what I want to do next after verifying that the count of the cookies stored is 2 is to dig in that cookie, decrypt it and ensure that the values are correct using the 'iv_key', the iv_key will then be used to decrypt a cookie that contains the user_key and check if it is existing in the database, at the same time the cookie that contains access_auth will also be decrypted and alter it's value depending on the user_key cookie's verification (returns true if user_key is found in database, otherwise false). Then after checking everything is legitimate, the cookies will then be re-encrypted using the same iv_key stored somewhere I don't know yet.

My question is and was, 'where is a safe location to store the encryption/decryption key?' and that is the 'iv_key'. I've read some threads and things about Session Variables, Local Storage, and Cookie. And I've put this things into consideration.

SESSION - I can use session storage of PHP to store the key in something like $_SESSION['user_key'] then access it later when needed be. But I've read an opinion saying that it is not recommended to store sensitive information including keys, passwords, or anything in session variable since they are stored somewhere on the server's public directory. And another thing is the session variable's lifespan, it lasts for around 30 minutes or so. I need to keep the key for as long as the user is logged in. The nice thing I find here is that, it'll be a little bit hard to alter the value and I don't need to encrypt it (the iv_key) here since it is server sided, and hidden to the naked eye, well not unless when being hacked of course. What I mean is, they don't appear on the debugging tools just like how localStorage and Cookies are visible there.

LOCAL STORAGE - this eliminates my problem of lifespan, since it will be stored in the localStorage vault of the browser not until I close the browser. But the problem here is that the values can easily be changed via console box of the debugger tool, I can eliminate this problem by encrypting the 'iv_key', but what's the point of encrypting the encryption/decryption key? Should I encrypt it using itself as the 'iv_key' too? Or I can use base64_encode?, which eliminates the security of needing a key, and can be decrypted so easily with no hassle.

COOKIE - this one adopts two problems, one from session variable and one from localstorage. From session variable, I mean is the lifespan. As far as I've read, cookies last for about 1 hour or so, but still depends if an expiry has been declared when setting the cookie. The other is from localStorage, since it can easily be altered via console box of the debugger tools too. Although I've already encrypted 2 Cookies beforehand, but what's the point of storing the encryption key together with the values you encrypted?, should I go on with this and encrypt the 'iv_key' by itself, just like what I might do with localStorage?.

I'm lost as to where I should save this sensitive 'encryption_key' as it is crucial in encrypting and decrypting the cookies and other information my app needs.

Why am I so devastated with such security, despite having a simple worthless app?.

Well, because I know and I believe that I can use this as a two-step further knowledge which I can used with my future projects. I maybe doing web development for fun right now. But I'm taking it to consideration as my profession. And so, I want my apps to be secure in any means.

Comment: Don't do this. Do some research on php token authentication.  There are a number of alternatives for doing authentication securely without trying to re-invent all the wheels you are attempting to build here.

Comment: i'll try and take a look at those. thanks anyway, but i still believe i have to make this one work tho :)

Comment: For server-side credential storage in PHP applications, this *may* be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11744957/2224584 -- I'm not sure what options are available in JavaScript.