# Where to securely put client_secret.json on Laravel application for Google Calendar OAuth

Tags: php, security, laravel-5, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have downloaded the `client_secret.json` file from my Google Developer Console for the OAuth of the my Google Calendar feature on my website.

Where should I put this file in my Laravel application so that this file will be secure and safe because it contains sensitive data

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a `client_secret.json` file. You can load in an array at runtime.

```
$configArray = [
    'client_id' => 'foo',
    'client_secret' => 'bar'
];
$client = new Google_Client($configArray);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301818/2224584) for how to securely load in sensitive data in PHP applications in order to populate this array.