# How to securely store multiple passwords on behalf of a user for external applications?

Tags: php, laravel, security, encryption, password-encryption

I'm building a web service and one of the included features involves storing passwords and credentials for users external applications.

My app is built using PHP/Laravel, the current security measures I've implemented are:

- Email and password login accompanied by compulsory two-factor authentication using Google Authenticator
- Once users are in they need to type in again a master password to access their database of credentials for their external applications.
- CSRF Protection and SSL

The passwords are stored in a MySQL database and encrypted using Laravel's encrypt() method and only decrypted (using the decrypt() method) and given to the user if the authenticated users session ID matches the ID in the row with the password credentials.

When a user requests a password credential is it pulled from the database using AJAX, decrypted and copied to the clipboard then deleted from the client side using javascript so the password is only available for a few seconds on the client side before it's back only in the database encrypted as it was before.

Edit: The key for encryption and decryption is Laravel's app key which is a single key stored in the environment file outside of the visible server files in the public folder.

My application is B2B SaaS and is used by mid-large sized clients meaning it needs to be secure. Please point out any flaws you see in my method or any other advice you think is relevant thanks.

Comment: The keys used for encryption/decryption, where are they generated/stored/derived from?  Provide more information about the keys themselves.

Comment: The key for encryption and decryption is Laravel's app key which is a single key stored in the environment file outside of the visible server files in the public folder.

Comment: Yeah that's a bad idea.  Use a unique key derived from the users master password when encrypting their other passwords.  This means that a data breach exposes literally nothing because you don't store the decryption key anywhere, it is provided by the user instead.

Comment: Ahh I see. So once a user has entered their master password how do I check if that was the actual original master password without storing a hash of it and comparing the two when it's submitted. Or should I just test it against one of their credentials and if it doesn't throw an exception then I know it is correct?

Comment: Decryption won't throw an exception for a wrong key, you'll just get an incorrect result.  Use an authenticated block mode or an HMAC if you want to be sure the password is correct before decryption.  GCM mode is perfect for this, see [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) for an example of AES-GCM in PHP.  If you can't use that, use an HMAC.

Comment: Just my 2ct: I would give every user their own public-private key pair for encrypting and decrypting the passwords.

Comment: @ThomasMoors Asymmetric cryptography isn't necessary here.  What advantage does this give over the solution I suggested above?  Remember that the server is the one doing the decryption.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark you are probably right!

Comment: @ThomasMoors Your idea would be great if the client was doing the decryption, because this would make the scheme E2E, but since the server is doing the decryption, I think it might be more work for no benefit.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Thanks for your suggestions. What if on the first time the user submits their master password I encrypt a random string using that master password and store the original string and the encrypted string in the database. Then when the type the master password the next time, I decrypt the string and see if the answer matches the answer I stored in the database. If not I'll research more into the methods you stated.

Comment: Industry standards say to use an AEAD (GCM Mode) or an HMAC, but what you have said would probably work fine too.

Comment: So, you're basically writing a password manager ... Please, don't. I mean, you've got some of the parts right, but if your need to ask StackOverflow how to do it, you're not qualified for it.

Comment: @Narf I think I know enough to build one. Was just looking for confirmation of my methods. There is going to be a bounty competition for anyone who can crack any password credentials within a month before launch. If it breaks, back to the drawing board - if it doesn't, it gets released publicly.

Comment: @user3858540 Sorry, but the cryptographic design here would be the key part, and you've reduced that part of the question to mentioning 2 functions available in Laravel - a framework known mostly for how unreasonably hyped it is. If that shows anything, it is that you're not ready for the task (making it work != working properly). And that bounty sounds wrong too ... If someone can crack it in a month, that's a complete disaster; what you need is a review by cryptographers to not show even theoretical flaws.

Comment: At the very least, you should've asked this on crypto.stackexchange as opposed to SO (here it's mostly about generic programming issues, not security). And I'm not trying to discourage you - experiment for personal use as much as you can! But when we start talking about storing other users' passwords, *online* - that's a very, very big deal; you can't ask strangers on the internet for help on that.

Comment: @Narf I used Laravel because it has good documentation and community support. PHP is wildly used and can be put on a server almost anywhere. The thing is, there are noobies spinning up websites everyday that use bcrypt hashing, they probably don't know what that is, but it works. And with significant protection against brute force attacks, there is no way a regular hacker is cracking the hash - its one way. Now if we look at that as an example, then look at my system (theoretically), with 5-6 layers of security before someone can access credentials. I think it's secure enough for B2B use.

Comment: @Narf I didn't put the full specification of my system for the question. I'm using 4 different methods of encryption in this application, I mentioned Laravel's encrypt/decrypt for simplicity. The bounty is a private bounty, it's not with real credentials. I have a cryptography/encryption/cybersecurity consulting agency who are going to view the code and try 18+ attack methods on it before I even do the bounty. I have precautions in place to make sure this goes fine for clients. Thanks for your suggestions however.

Comment: @user3858540 How did this go?

Comment: I believe the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11744957/2224584) will be helpful to this question.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I know this is a bit of a late response but the project went well. It's been live for a couple months in a web applications supplying a couple hundred users without any security issues so far. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to *not* do it.

Put another way: If you can get away with not storing passwords (i.e. using OAuth2 instead), don't store passwords. You don't want the extra liability.

That being said, sometimes you literally cannot avoid storing passwords (e.g. IMAP integrations). In this case, always [start with a threat model](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/07/20/threat-modeling-for-applications) before you delve too far into the weeds.

- If someone hacks your database (e.g. SQL injection), what can they access?

  - Can they access the filesystem and read the encryption keys?
  - Can they rewrite ciphertexts from a targeted user's account into the field for an account they already hace access to, and thereby gain access to the plaintext without first obtaining the encryption key?

> When a user requests a password credential is it pulled from the database using AJAX, decrypted and copied to the clipboard then deleted from the client side using javascript so the password is only available for a few seconds on the client side before it's back only in the database encrypted as it was before.

It sounds like you're reimplementing a password manager. You might want to shepherd your customers towards something like KeePassXC or 1Password instead.

Since this decryption doesn't include any user-provided secrets, the webserver must therefore be capable of decrypting all of your users' passwords. So if an attacker can hack the webserver, they get all of the users' passwords for free.

If you're dead set on partially reinventing password managers, you're going to want to embrace the [principle of least authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and make your server unable to decrypt your users' passwords.

This means using client-side encryption, where your server is a black box that only stores ciphertext.